# An NPN transistor without its collector-base voltage

Tags: voltage, transistors, npn, common-base

What would happen if I **remove the base-collector voltage** from an NPN transistor and put a wire connecting two ends of the voltage source? I believe that it it will work nicely. As the collector current (Ic) doesn't depend on Vcb, won't we get **same current amplification when we had Vcb in our circuit?**

Comment: Define *"remove"* here.

Comment: *What would happen if* - you should be able to just try it and answer the question yourself. *I believe that* - no need for that, even as a figure of speech. Experiment trumps everything :) It's not hard at all to just try. Should take less time than asking here.

Comment: You need to clarify what you mean ny *remove the base-collector voltage*, since it has no bearing on the operation of the transistor.

Comment: I meant I took away the Voltage source and put a wire connecting both end of the Voltage source.

Comment: No voltage source then no current aside from base current.  And you need to add this to your question, not in the comments.  And you still need more details.

Comment: Imagine you have an n-p-n transistor. When we have the Emitter-Base voltage source, it helps to start pulling electrons from Emitter. Then very few electrons or holes recombine in Base region which is liable for Base-current. And rest of the electrons have the other path from collector to base. Besides, the electric field from n to p type doped region is aiding the motion of electrons toward the collector. Shouldn't there be an electric flow as the electric field in collector junction is aiding the electrons to move along the path where I replaced the Voltage source with the wire?

Comment: Please provide a schematic or sketch of what you propose, showing expected voltages and currents. Do a simulation and show results.

Answer (score 4):

If you disconnect (open circuit) the collector, then no collector current will flow. At any base current, the transistor will saturate (i.e. VCE will be very small), and it will basically behave as a (poor) diode between Band E.

Answer (score 2):

> As the collector current(Ic) doesn't depend on Vcb ...

This is the faulty assertion.

It's a good approximation of transistor behaviour when V<sub>CB</sub> > a few volts.

It fails when V<sub>CB</sub> is less than that

Comment: So the right assumption will be : 
1. Collector current depends on Vcb up to a level and the level is **potential barrier**. 
2. When Vcb is higher than the potential barrier, this time collector current also depends on Vcb. The more Vcb, the more collector current. Am I right?

Comment: @IsteakAhamedImon No. When Vcb is zero or small, collector current is strongly dependent on Vbc - assuming a constant forward Vbe. As Vcb exceeds a volt or two, then collector current becomes approximately independent of Vcb. Take a look at almost any transistor datasheet for graphs of Ic vs Vcb+Ib.

Answer (score 1):

The assumptions for Ic vs Vbe are that Vce> 2V for linear power amplifiers.  For small signals, it is less but for hFE it is often specified at Vce=4V.

When Vce moves towards 0V, Vcb becomes forward biased and hFE drops rapidly.  Vc provides the output voltage gain for common emitters so Vcb is essential.

Answer (score 1):

The BE junction will behave  like a diode.

However current won't enter the collector? Why? Because current needs a path to flow, it cannot jump!

Comment: I meant I took away the Voltage source and put a wire connecting both end of the Voltage source.

Comment: So you replaced the voltage source with a short circuit?

Comment: My bad! I joined this platform today. I couldn't explain my words properly. Sorry for that. If I add a resistor there, then I hope the current will flow. Right?

Comment: Shouldn't it be a lot higher than base current? Because Base is lightly doped and very few electrons or holes undergo recombination which construct a little base current. And the rest of the electrons will make a higher Collector current.

Comment: No because the transistor is in saturation.The situation you describe is only when the transistor is in forward active mode.When the current gets too big that KVL gives us negative VCE or when the voltage of the base>voltage of the collector then the transistor is in saturation mode.